# Excel VBA: Loop through text files to remove string within file

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Add-In that I've developed that takes Electronic Data Interchange files and imports specific fields within those files into Excel. Some files contain datatypes that cannot be processed. My current workflow is to search for those files and delete them. However, some files contain data that should be processing. I'm looking for a solution to loop through each file, search for specific datatypes, and remove the entire section from the text file.

**Data Example:**

*2FRM Hello World! 5DEL Bad Datatype 6OTH Other Data 2FRM Insert Me 5FOR Valid Datatype*

In this example, 2FRM would be the beginning of a section. I would like to locate the 5DEL group, then remove the entire string/section it is contained within. This would mean deleting from 2FRM up until the next 2FRM.

**Data Example After Fix:**

*2FRM Insert Me 5FOR Valid Datatype*

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: What code do you have so far for this attempt? Look at using `Instr` and `Mid` just for starters.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [InStr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) function. I've used this method a ton with great success.

```
Public Function FileImport()

    Dim searchStart As String, searchEnd As String, fullString As String, stringEnd As Long, startLoc As Long, endLoc As Long

    searchStart = "5DEL"
    searchEnd = "2FRM"
    'File open/loop code goes somewhere and fullString is set to the data contained within. I'm manually setting this as an example below:

    fullString = "2FRM Hello World! 5DEL Bad Datatype 6OTH Other Data 2FRM Insert Me 5FOR Valid Datatype"

    stringEnd = Len(fullString)

    If stringEnd > 0 Then 'Skip the section if the string blank.
        Do
            startLoc = InStr(1, fullString, searchStart, vbTextCompare) 'Find the piece of text we are looking for.
            If startLoc > 0 Then 'We have found the starting location of 5DEL in the string.
                endLoc = InStr(startLoc, fullString, searchEnd, vbTextCompare) 'Find end of the bad string, starting from the starting location.
                If endLoc > 0 Then 'A starting and ending location were found.
                    fullString = Left(fullString, startLoc - 1) & Mid(fullString, endLoc, Len(fullString))
                Else 'No ending location was found, thus we only need the left part of the string.
                    fullString = Left(fullString, startLoc - 1)
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Else
                Exit Do 'The bad string was not found, exit.
            End If
            DoEvents 'Just so that the application does not become non-responsive. Can be removed.
        Loop
    End If

    Debug.Print fullString
    'Output is 2FRM Hello World! 2FRM Insert Me 5FOR Valid Datatype

    'File open/loop code ends.

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need an Excel formula you could use

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("2FRM",A1,5)+1)
```

Assumes the data "2FRM Hello World! 5DEL Bad Datatype 6OTH Other Data 2FRM Insert Me 5FOR Valid Datatype" is in cell A1

Or in VBA

```
Public Function CleanData(sData As String) As String
Dim sFind As String, iLen As Integer

    sFind = "2FRM"
    iLen = Len(sFind)
    If Left(sData, iLen) = sFind Then CleanData = Right(sData, Len(sData) - InStr(iLen + 1, sData, sFind) + 1)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Instr to find the first 5DEL. Then Use Instr to find the first 2FRM that follows, and InStrRev to find the 2FRM that precedes.

```
f = "2FRM KeepMe1 4DEL KeepMe2 2FRM dontKeepMe3 5DEL dontKeepMe4 2FRM dontKeepMe5 5DEL dontKeepMe6 2FRM KeepMe7 4DEL KeepMe8 "
a2 = InStr(f, "5DEL")
Do While a2 <> 0
 a1 = InStrRev(f, "2FRM", a2)
 a3 = InStr(a2, f, "2FRM")
 If a3 = 0 Then a3 = Len(f) + 1
 f = Mid(f, 1, a1 - 1) & Mid(f, a3)
 a2 = InStr(f, "5DEL")
Loop
```